# Angular: Custom structural directive doesn't work

Tags: angular

As part of an angular tutorial I've tried to create a custom structural directive.

Google nor stackoverflow search was able to provide the required information to solve this problem.

The code looks as follows:

```js
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRole]'
})
export class RoleDirective {
  private role: string;
  private hasView = false;

  get appRole() {
    return this.role;
  }

  @Input()
  set appRole(value: string) {
    this.role = value;
    const access = this.hasRolePermission( value );
    if ( access && !this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView( this.template );
      this.hasView = true;
    } else if ( access && !this.hasView ) {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.hasView = false;
    }
  }

  constructor(
    private template: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

    hasRolePermission( role: string ): boolean {
      return role === environment.role;
    }
}
```

The directive is exported in the respective module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RoleDirective } from './role.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [RoleDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [RoleDirective]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

Below the template used:

```html
<header>
  <h1 appHover="red">Benutzer</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <app-user-list [ngStyle]="style">
  </app-user-list>
  <button *appRole="admin">Administration</button>
  <button *appRole="user">Benutzer</button>
</main>

<footer>
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="company">
    <img *ngSwitchCase="'omega'" src="../assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    <img *ngSwitchCase="'alphaAndOmega'" src="../assets/img/alphaAndOmega.jpg" alt="logo">
    <img *ngSwitchDefault src="../assets/img/angularLogo.png" alt="angular">
  </ng-container>

  <img *ngIf="showOmega; else elseBlock" src="../assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
  <button id="logo" (click)="toggleLogo()">
    Zeige Logo "Alpha and Omega"
  </button>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <img src="../assets/img/alphaAndOmega.jpg" alt="logo">
  </ng-template>
</footer>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

During aot compilation I receive an error message, that the property doesn't exists the type:

```
ERROR in src\app\app.component.html(8,11): : Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
src\app\app.component.html(9,11): : Property 'user' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

Any help or pointers on how to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

with kind regards,
Patrik

Comment: Can you please share the code of your app.component.ts. It seems there are no variables admin or user

Comment: The file "environment.prod.ts" defined the role. I compile the code using the "--configuration production". The code looks as follows: ```export const environment = {
  production: true,
  role: ' admin'
};

```

Comment: `*appRole="admin"`. Either you declare admin in your AppComponent or you pass a string `*appRole="'admin'"`, since you are requesting a string in your directive `@Input()
  set appRole(value: string)`

Comment: Unfortunately the directive doesn't work as expected. I pass a string now (```<button *appRole="'admin'">Administration</button>```), but the button still is not rendered.

Comment: Did you mean something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yht4oy ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I had to quote the strings in the template. First it did not work, as I've also missed a typo I've made in the environment file - but now all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing a string into the appRole directive, you need to quote it - otherwise, it's looking for a property of that name to supply the value.

Try

```
<button *appRole="'admin'">Administration</button>
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your feedback. It is working now as expected.